# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I ask user to enter min_number and max_number. For example user set min_number: 2 and max_number: 6

Random give me [3, 5] and this error

> random = random.sample(range(1, 80), min_number)
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

```
while min_number <= max_number:
        random = random.sample(range(1, 10), min_number)
        print (random)
        for j in random:
            element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[{j}]/div')))
            element.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            j += j

        min_number += min_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because random is the name of your lib.

Try renaming `random =` in `arandom =` for instance

With the code below no error anymore:

```
import random
while 2 <= 3:
        arandom = random.sample(range(1, 10), k=1)
        print (arandom)
        for j in arandom:
          
            j += j
```

Comment: Yes, this is. Previously I have called random1, random2, random3.. then now change to one loop